# How to group elements in array in template

Tags: javascript, meteor, each, meteor-blaze

I have an array of elements 14 to be exact and I would like to display them in the template. Im using `{{#each tasks}}`, but I would a way to group the elements together on the front end so I would have `task1` and `task2` grouped in a `div` and then `3 & 4` in another div and so on.

```
{{#each tasks}}
  <div class="task-group">
   {{task 1}}
   {{task 2}}
  </div>
{{/endeach}}
```

How could I go about doing this in Meteor.

Comment: I think that you need to convert this array somewhere in controller into array with groups. And then you can easily make double-iteration.

Comment: Ah that's helpful. I don't suppose you know of any ways of doing this with JavaScript.

Comment: You can try this. But you need to handle case, when number of elements is odd (or last element will be undefined)
function groupedArr(arr) {
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
    res.push([arr[i],arr[i+1]]);
  }
  return res;
}

This example just for 2 elements group. But i think you got the idea.

Comment: Odd it didnt work, I wonder if its how Meteor disseminates information from Mongo

Comment: Can you provide example of data? How tasks looks?

Comment: Well they are being pulled from a Mongo DB, so its a collection of data, i use Blaze to loop through it using {{#each}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73936/discussion-between-nikolay-talanov-and-sam-mason).

Comment: I think I answered this on your other question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301650/each-loop-over-multiple-documents-from-a-collection-in-a-single-iteration/29304488#29304488

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be late but for those that want to accomplish this. i later figured it out from my experience with ruby on rails.

first on all in you helper define a function like this

```
splittedArray: function () {
    let items = Collection.find().fetch()
    let size = 2;
    let arrays = [];

    while (items.length > 0)
        arrays.push(items.splice(0, size));
    return arrays
}
```

Where `size` is the amount of items you want in a group

the value returned will be a an array with multiple arrays inside

you can now literate in your blaze template as simple as this

```
{{#each splittedArray}}
   {{#each this}}
      {{name}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Hope this helps