# #each loop over multiple documents from a collection in a single iteration

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor collection called `Tasks`

I would like to display them on the template with a div wrapped around every 2.

So something like this

```
<div>
  {{task 1}}
  {{ task 2 }}
</div>

<div>
  {{task 3}}
  {{ task 4 }}
</div>
```

How would I got about doing this in Meteor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a helper to define what you want to iterate over -- in this case, you could do something like return an array of objects that contain the first and second tasks you want to display:

```
<template name='whatever'>
  {{#each getTasksToIterate}}
    <div>
      {{> task firstTask}}
      {{> task secondTask}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
```

Then, in your helpers, define the function `getTasksToIterate`:

```
Template.whatever.helpers({
  getTasksToIterate: function() { 
    var tasks = [];
    _.each(this.tasks, function(task, index) { 
      if (index % 2 === 0) { // Pick the odd ones
        tasks.push({firstTask: elem, secondTask: this.tasks[index + 1]}); 
      }

    return tasks;
  }
});
```

Note that this assumes you have an even number of tasks; if you occasionally have an odd number you'd need to deal with that with appropriate if statements, etc.

Comment: This also assumes you have a data context with tasks available . If you're prototyping and using autopublish, replace `_.each(this.tasks...` with `Tasks.find().forEach(...)`; the documentation for that function is here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/foreach, and you can use the third argument to the callback function in place of further references to this.tasks.